# Error while installing RSelenium in R

Tags: r, rselenium

I am getting following error when I try to install the `RSelenium` package.

```
install.packages("RSelenium")  
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/nshukla/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)  
Warning in install.packages :  
  dependency ‘binman’ is not available  
also installing the dependencies ‘subprocess’, ‘semver’, ‘wdman’

There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
             binary source needs_compilation  
  RSelenium  1.6.2  1.7.1             FALSE    

Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:  
  ‘subprocess’ ‘semver’  
  These will not be installed
installing the source packages ‘wdman’, ‘RSelenium’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/wdman_0.2.2.tar.gz'  
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 26342 bytes (25 KB)  
downloaded 25 KB  

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RSelenium_1.7.1.tar.gz'  
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4303990 bytes (4.1 MB)  
downloaded 4.1 MB
```

> ERROR: dependencies 'binman', 'subprocess', 'semver' are not available
>   for package 'wdman'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/nshukla/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/wdman'
>   Warning in install.packages :   running command
>   '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -1
>   "C:\Users\nshukla\Documents\R\win-library\3.2"
>   C:\Users\nshukla\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuAuA2g/downloaded_packages/wdman_0.2.2.tar.gz'
>   had status 1
>
> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>    ‘wdman’ had non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies 'wdman', 'binman'
>    are not available for package 'RSelenium'
>    * removing 'C:/Users/nshukla/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/RSelenium'
>
> Warning in install.packages :   running command
>   '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l
>   "C:\Users\nshukla\Documents\R\win-library\3.2"
>   C:\Users\nshukla\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuAuA2g/downloaded_packages/RSelenium_1.7.1.tar.gz'
>   had status 1
>
> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>   ‘RSelenium’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 3):

The `binman` package imports `semver` to parse semantic version strings. This depends on C++11. A version of R >= 3.3.0 is needed to install this. You would need to upgrade your version of R.

Comment: I get compilation failure error for package `semver`. I'm using R 3.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
install.packages('RSelenium', type="win.binary")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
    library(devtools)
    install_version("binman", version = "0.1.0", repos = "https://cran.uni-muenster.de/")
    install_version("wdman", version = "0.2.2", repos = "https://cran.uni-muenster.de/")
    install_version("RSelenium", version = "1.7.1", repos = "https://cran.uni-muenster.de/")
```

This is the answer of FabianFox on the github page: https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/172