# when I try to install RSelenium package in R, I have got this error [error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘parameter’ with no type [-fpermissive]]

Tags: c++, r, linux, c++11, rstudio-server

I have to install RSelenium package in R studio server on Linux, 
however I've found these error messages. 
I want to know the cause and the solution.

```
###error message after install.packages("RSelenium")

semver200.h:51:60: error: ‘Prerelease_identifiers’ does not name a type
semver200.h:51:82: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘parameter’ with no 
type [-fpermissive]
semver200.h:52:55: error: ‘Build_identifiers’ does not name a type
semver200.h:52:72: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘parameter’ with no 
type [-fpermissive]
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘semver’
* removing ‘/home/data/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/semver’
Error: Command failed (1) ####end
```

Comment: Try to reinstall the package semver and Rcpp.

Comment: I reinstalled Rcpp successfully, however I failed to install semver package and I have found these error again. //////semver200.h:52:55: error: ‘Build_identifiers’ does not name a type
semver200.h:52:72: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘parameter’ with no type [-fpermissive]////
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘semver’

Comment: Try to remove the package semver, then install it again, please. I think your package may be out of date.

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440911/error-while-installing-rselenium-in-r

Comment: Which version is your semver? The newest version of semver is 0.2.0, which means it is under testing phase, and maybe has some compilation errors.

Comment: The semver whose version is the newest can be installed on my PC.